# How to revert back to a page if no userInteraction for timeInterval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a HomePage and a PayYourBill page, on the PayYourBill page, the user is going to enter critical information, Is it possible to revert back to HomePage if there is no interaction for 'x' periodOfTime, do I have to use `session`, or is it possible without it?

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript for this. You could set a timer on the page that gets reset every time the users interacts with the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript with a timer that will reset if there is any interaction on the page.

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) are the function names.

Comment: can you share the syntax?please

Comment: @yatida - The details are in the links.

Comment: @Oded, with Rep 1? But you will get +1 from me

Comment: temporary id so can't upvote ! will do so with my permanent id :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using setTimeOut in javascript.

Add event handlers that you find important, such as mouseover on your input elements. In those event handlers clearTimeout and set a new timeout.

If the users have not done anything just change the page by setting window.location to your HomePage